# Date-time stamp in sends & opens data view in marketing cloud is not in sync with local time

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, datetime, data-views, tracking-extract

I'm using salesforce marketing cloud for sending emailers. Date time settings in my account are set as per IST (Indian standard time), GMT + 5:30.

Though when I fetch data from "Sends" & "Opens" data view from standard system data extension, I'm getting different date time. The time found there is around 11 hours behind the local time (GMT+5:30).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The system date time for Marketing Cloud is almost always in CST.

In your query you can just convert the CST time to your timezone.

To adjust it by 11 hours.

```
SELECT
DATEADD(hour, 11, s.EventDate) as SentDate
FROM _Sent as s
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this.
Just be advised this solution works only in case your locality does not observe daylight savings time, where the offset (here: 11) changes every half year.

Answer (score 0):

Had a word with customer support regarding this.

Got to know that it's server time & is CST. (GMT - 6:00).

So I'll have to convert GMT-6:00 to GMT+5:30.